# Is my mobile AMD card being used?

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio, ati-mobility-radeon, switchable-graphics

I have a new Sony E Series Vaio with an intel i5 and an AMD 7xxx mobile card. Despite making sure sure my app (game) is set to High Performance in switchable gfx and choosing high performance power plan I'm not entirely convinced the gfx card is being used over the CPU's HD4000 chipset. Is there anyway I can prove for sure the AMD card is being used?

thanks for reading

(OS is Win8 64bit)

Comment: Go into the BIOS and disable integrated video...?

Comment: One does not simply open the BIOS on a modern vaio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the AMD Catalyst Center, go to the "switchable Graphic Application settings", click on "Add application" and select the exe of the game and set it to high performance.

Now download the tool call [OpenHardwareMonitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) and add the AMD Radeon HD7700 settings to the Gadget. if the GPU is not used you see this:

[image]

If the GPU is used you see this:

[image]

Comment: +1 for CCC and add application. I learned something new.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use [GPU Z](http://www.filehippo.com/download_gpuz/). It will suppy you with information about you GPU and you can log activity. If there is more than one card, you can select each one, one at a time, and see what is being used and how much with the log to track activity.

Below image is where you can select your graphics card in the drop down if there is more than one.

[image: GPUZ1]

[image: GPUZ2]

Here is a sample log I pulled from my laptop:
[image: Logoutput]

Comment: this doesn't work for my HD7700, because GPU-Z hangs at startup when the GPU is not used. That's why I use the OHM Gadget to see the activity.